# How to fix "Cannot read property 'toDataURL' of undefined" in angular2-signaturePad

Tags: angular, npm

I am building a project that uses Angular 7. I am currently trying to implement signature and save the signature image in database. So I choose "angular2-signaturepad" package to implement the signature.It is working fine till the draw completes. After the completion of the signature draw I want to save the image. But it showing the error "Cannot read property 'toDataURL' of undefined" after the draw complete.

In html file

`<signature-pad [options]='signaturePadOptions' (onBeginEvent)="drawBegin()" (onEndEvent)="drawComplete()"></signature-pad>`

in ts file

`import { SignaturePad } from "angular2-signaturepad/signature-pad";`

inside oninit

````
  @ViewChild('SignaturePad') signaturePad: SignaturePad;
  public SignaturePadOptions = {
    'minWidth':2,
    'penColor':'rgb(66,133,244)',
    'backgroundColor':'rgb(255,255,255)',
    'canvasWidth':450,
    'canvasHeight':150,
  };
  public drawBegin(): void {
    console.log('Begin Drawing');
  }

  public drawComplete(): void {
    let signature = this.signaturePad.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.5);
    console.log(signature);
  }
}```



I expect the output should be the base url image name while console the result. But it is showing error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDataURL' of undefined".
````

Comment: can you show us the line where `this.signaturePad` is actually defined?

Comment: @Woohoojin I edited the code in question. You can view now where the signaturePad is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I get such problem with ionic 4,because Ionic executes constructor before the view finishes to render.
see this may it help
https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad/issues/412

Answer (score 1):

Found this in a comment from [znotdead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173627/znotdead) on another question: [There is a signature pad for Angular that save it to image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59045961/there-is-a-signature-pad-for-angular-that-save-it-to-image)

Change the import statement from:

```
   import { SignaturePad } from "angular2-signaturepad/signature-pad";
```

to

```
   import { SignaturePad } from 'angular2-signaturepad';
```

Answer (score 0):

try add this

```
 ionViewDidEnter() {
   var canvas =document.querySelector('canvas');
   this.signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add explanation to your code.

Comment: I get such error with ionic 4 .  Ionic executes constructor before the view finishes to render, please see this link may it help https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad/issues/412

Answer (score 0):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('signature pad', this.signaturePad);
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me like this:

```
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {
}
ionViewDidEnter() {
    const canvas = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('canvas');
    this.signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
}
```