# There is a signature pad for Angular that save it to image?

Tags: angular

I need to make a signature pad and save it.
I work on enterprise site and i need to save signature per user.
What the best package for this?

Comment: could you get the image?

Comment: @jecorrales Yes, it has data url or PNG.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do a google search you can easily find many libraries for your requirement.
I recently use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-signaturepad) signaturepad module so I can recommend it.

Install it using:

```
npm install angular2-signaturepad --save
```

Then import it in your app.module.ts.

```
import { SignaturePadModule } from 'angular2-signaturepad';
```

Then add it to imports:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
              SignaturePadModule
             ]
})
```

You can call the directive in your html like this:

```
<signature-pad [options]="signaturePadOptions"  id="signatureCanvas"></signature-pad>
```

In your .ts file you can define its behaviors like this.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from 'angular2/core';
import { SignaturePad } from 'angular2-signaturepad/signature-pad';

@Component({
  template: '<signature-pad [options]="signaturePadOptions" (onBeginEvent)="drawStart()" (onEndEvent)="drawComplete()"></signature-pad>'
})

export class SignaturePadPage{

  @ViewChild(SignaturePad) signaturePad: SignaturePad;

  private signaturePadOptions: Object = { // passed through to szimek/signature_pad constructor
    'minWidth': 5,
    'canvasWidth': 500,
    'canvasHeight': 300
  };

  constructor() {
    // no-op
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.signaturePad.set('minWidth', 5);
    this.signaturePad.clear();
  }

  drawComplete() {
    console.log(this.signaturePad.toDataURL());
  }

  drawStart() {
    console.log('begin drawing');
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask any question if you face into issues.

Comment: It worked with Angular 8. It will support Angular 9 but this is outdated now. So better  move to something new. :)

Comment: It works with angular 9. Change import though to: `import { SignaturePad } from 'angular2-signaturepad';`

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I'm getting this error `'signature-pad' is not a known element:`

Comment: This worked for me today exactly as Koga described, with the updated tweak from znotdead!